# Building a pipeline for multiple-repository services

Tags: python, build, continuous-integration, multiple-repositories

I'm developing a service in Python which has a package as a dependency. I've developed that dependency myself.
I have a private PyPI server that contains artifacts(a wheel file) of every commit in the master branch(for both packages).
I'd like to create a CI which will use pip to install the dependency from the private PyPI server(because it's faster and easier than installing from the source code itself every time).

**Example for the project's dependencies:**

> packages A requires package B
> (which are all in the private repository and not public packages).

My problem is that if I'm trying to execute a CI on the A repository right after the B repository had a merge to master,
the private PyPI server won't have the latest version of B yet(Today there's a Jenkins job that is activated after every merge to master and uploads the B wheel to the private PyPI server,
but it takes a few minutes until the package is being built). The result is that package A might contain an old version of B instead of using the latest version of B.

Any suggestion on how to improve this process?

Installing from a private PyPI, in comparison to installing directly from Gitlab decreases the time it takes to install dramatically.

BTW, today I am using Gitlab's enterprise edition and Jenkins.

Thanks

Comment: We support this behaviour via Reliza Hub (I'm working on the tool) - basically, the idea is that at CI phase - artifact creation - you submit dependency metadata to Reliza Hub. Then Reliza Hub would create bundles for you - then you resolve those bundles at CD phase. You can find me on DevOps Discord - https://discord.gg/UTxjBf9juQ - will help you set this up.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to check if package B is up-to-date before you start the installation of A. So (in your Jenkins job) just put a build step to download everything for B, and after that everything for A.

Comment: What do you mean by "download everything for B"?

Comment: source code to create wheel file

Comment: Are you suggesting that when i'm building A, if B is not built, that I should build it as well?

Comment: You wrote package A requires package B. So if you want to be sure that code for B is up-to-date you should check changes on Git and if there are changes then build B.